# Redis Security per client basis

Tags: rabbitmq

I am creating an application which will provide services to clients(other software).

My Application will generate data for its clients and after processing it store it inside its databases and as well as on Redis master server.

I don't want different clients to hit my application instead I want they will retrieve data related to them from the Redis cluster itself.  It will reduce the amount of traffic coming into my application. As per my Design, My application is only responsible for generating the data and updating the Redis server at some specified time and the different client can go retrieve data from the Redis server itself.

But I am not able to decide how to allow client1 from viewing the data of client2?

One thing I can think of is to encrypt the actual data by the public key of the client because now even if client2 get the data related to the client he won't be able to decrypt it. But still, I don't trust this approach much is there any other solve this problem?

Edited:

For people having same problem. I have found a solution. For above scenario instead of using redis, I Have used rabbitmq queues for handling above use case.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be a Redis database (i.e. single-instance or cluster) per client. This will make your life and administrating the thing much easier.